# Azure Maps: symbols disappear on collision despite allowOverlap and ignorePlacement

Tags: javascript, azure-maps

I'm creating a map and then a symbol layer as shown below. However symbols still disappear when I zoom out almost completely. What can be reason for that?

```
  const newSymbolLayer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(source, undefined, {
    iconOptions: {
      ignorePlacement: true,
      allowOverlap: true,
      optional: false,
      image: [
        ...
      ],
      ...
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason was not in the SymbolLayer options, but in the Datasource that was used with this SymbolLayer. That's how it was declared:

```
const newDatasource = new atlas.source.DataSource(undefined, {
  cluster: true,
});
```

I've copied it from Microsoft Learn examples and didn't give a proper thought to what a cluster means. Now, when I change `cluster` to `false`, icons ignore collision as I intended:

```
const newDatasource = new atlas.source.DataSource(undefined, {
  cluster: false,
});
```

This article helped me find this solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1055021/azure-indoor-maps-pins-markers-are-not-visible-whe

Comment: Great. Glad you found the issue and shared it back. Clustering is great when you have a lot of points the clutter the map, but if you weren't expecting it, it can definitely see odd.